# scons trying to link to wrong boost libs

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to compile my project as a shared library using scons.  I'm using Windows 7, and the Visual Studio 2013 RC.  In the project, I'm using boost.

The project compiles fine.  However, when it tries to link, I get the following:

```
scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Compiling Glr
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Parsing Shaders into header ShaderData.h
Done parsing Shaders into header ShaderData.h
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Using tempfile c:\users\jarrett\appdata\local\temp\tmpecwym3.lnk for command line:
link /nologo /dll /out:build\glr.dll /implib:build\glr.lib /LIBPATH:build /LIBPATH:src /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\angelscript-sdk\angelscript\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\sqlite3 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\berkelium-win32\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\SFML\lib "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Assimp\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\FreeImage\Dist "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" opengl32.lib glew32.lib berkelium.lib sfml-system.lib sfml-window.lib assimp.lib freeimage.lib libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_wave-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_54.lib build\BasicSceneManager.obj build\BasicSceneNode.obj build\Camera.obj build\GlrProgram.obj build\GraphicsEngine.obj build\Light.obj build\Window.obj build\common\math\Math.obj build\common\io\File.obj build\BasicSceneManager.obj build\BasicSceneNode.obj build\Camera.obj build\GlrProgram.obj build\GraphicsEngine.obj build\Light.obj build\Window.obj build\exceptions\Exception.obj build\exceptions\FormatException.obj build\exceptions\GlException.obj build\exceptions\IoException.obj build\gui\CallbackParameter.obj build\gui\GUI.obj build\gui\GUIObject.obj build\gui\HtmlGuiComponent.obj build\models\Animation.obj build\models\AssImpLoader.obj build\models\Model.obj build\models\ModelLoader.obj build\models\ModelManager.obj build\glw\Animation.obj build\glw\AnimationManager.obj build\glw\Constants.obj build\glw\Material.obj build\glw\MaterialManager.obj build\glw\Mesh.obj build\glw\MeshManager.obj build\glw\OpenGlDevice.obj build\glw\Texture.obj build\glw\TextureManager.obj build\glw\shaders\CPreProcessor.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrParser.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrPreProcessor.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrShader.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrShaderProgram.obj build\glw\shaders\GlslShader.obj build\glw\shaders\GlslShaderProgram.obj build\glw\shaders\ShaderProgramManager.obj
link @c:\users\jarrett\appdata\local\temp\tmpecwym3.lnk
Using tempfile c:\users\jarrett\appdata\local\temp\tmpep9gzl.lnk for command line:
link /nologo /dll /out:build\glr.dll /implib:build\glr.lib /LIBPATH:build /LIBPATH:src /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\angelscript-sdk\angelscript\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\sqlite3 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\berkelium-win32\lib /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\SFML\lib "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Assimp\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Jarrett\projects\FreeImage\Dist "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib" opengl32.lib glew32.lib berkelium.lib sfml-system.lib sfml-window.lib assimp.lib freeimage.lib libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_wave-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_regex-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_54.lib libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_54.lib build\BasicSceneManager.obj build\BasicSceneNode.obj build\Camera.obj build\GlrProgram.obj build\GraphicsEngine.obj build\Light.obj build\Window.obj build\common\math\Math.obj build\common\io\File.obj build\BasicSceneManager.obj build\BasicSceneNode.obj build\Camera.obj build\GlrProgram.obj build\GraphicsEngine.obj build\Light.obj build\Window.obj build\exceptions\Exception.obj build\exceptions\FormatException.obj build\exceptions\GlException.obj build\exceptions\IoException.obj build\gui\CallbackParameter.obj build\gui\GUI.obj build\gui\GUIObject.obj build\gui\HtmlGuiComponent.obj build\models\Animation.obj build\models\AssImpLoader.obj build\models\Model.obj build\models\ModelLoader.obj build\models\ModelManager.obj build\glw\Animation.obj build\glw\AnimationManager.obj build\glw\Constants.obj build\glw\Material.obj build\glw\MaterialManager.obj build\glw\Mesh.obj build\glw\MeshManager.obj build\glw\OpenGlDevice.obj build\glw\Texture.obj build\glw\TextureManager.obj build\glw\shaders\CPreProcessor.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrParser.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrPreProcessor.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrShader.obj build\glw\shaders\GlrShaderProgram.obj build\glw\shaders\GlslShader.obj build\glw\shaders\GlslShaderProgram.obj build\glw\shaders\ShaderProgramManager.obj
build\BasicSceneManager.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\BasicSceneNode.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\Camera.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\GlrProgram.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\GraphicsEngine.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\Light.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
build\Window.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_log-vc110-mt-1_54.lib'
scons: building terminated because of errors.
scons: *** [build/glr.dll] Error 1104
```

I'm curious why it's trying to link to `libboost_log-vc110-mt-1_54.lib` instead of `libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_54.lib`, which is what I specified in the link command.  Also, as far as I can tell, `vcxxx` is the compiler tag boost uses to tell what version of the compiler built the boost library...so it's almost like `scons` thinks boost was built using Visual Studio 2012, which would be `vc110`...I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is an issue with boost 1.54 not being aware of MSVC 2013.

I downloaded the boost trunk (1.55), compiled, and it linked properly.